# Calculate Average Vector Value Based on Points in Polygon

Tags: polygon, vector, statistics, average

I initially had two layers that I "joined attributes by location." Now I have one layer.

In this layer I have several points with values from 1 - 10 and several polygons that are census tracts. I want to find the average value of my points per census tract. Is there a way to do this easily. I have found `v.vect.stats` with GRASS GIS but I do not have much experience with that and was wondering if there was a quicker workaround.

Comment: You mean that you have a polygon attribute on each point? You cant have one layer that is both points and polygons

Answer (score 0):

Use [Statistics by categories](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisstatisticsbycategories):

> Calculates statistics of a field depending on a parent class. The
> parent class is a combination of values from other fields.

Or [Join attributes by location (summary)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinbylocationsummary)

> Takes an input vector layer and creates a new vector layer that is an
> extended version of the input one, with additional attributes in its
> attribute table.
>
> The additional attributes and their values are taken from a second
> vector layer. A spatial criteria is applied to select the values from
> the second layer that are added to each feature from the first layer.
>
> The algorithm calculates a statistical summary for the values from
> matching features in the second layer (e.g. maximum value, mean value,
> etc).

Comment: I don't believe either of those have what I am looking for.   

I ideally would have a column in my attribute table (or a separate layer altogether) that had average of point value per census tract. I am hoping to create a map with the average value of each census tract.

Comment: Join attribute by location summary, then join the output table to your polygons.